What is the runtime of this function and why?
There are many similar questions to this, but I haven't seen this variation.
void myFunc(int n) {
    int sum;
    int i, j;
    sum = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j += 1) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    for(i = 1; i <= sum; i += 1) {
        cout<<”func2 is awesome!”<<endl;
    }
}


https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Have you tried working through this?  What did you come up with so far?

@StephenNewell i came up with O(n^2)

That's what I'd go with too unless I'm reading the code wrong.  Why aren't you confident with your answer?  Why not [edit] your question with your analysis and why you're unsure.

The first nested for loops time complexity would be O(n^2). The sum got from the for loops the time complexity above would be n * n * (n + 1) / 2 so the last for loop would be O(n * n * (n + 1) / 2) -> O(n^3) so the total time complexity would be
O(n^2 + n^3) -> O(n^3)


The first nested loop iterates from 1 to n for both i and j. Within this loop, a constant time operation is performed, which is the addition of i to sum. Therefore, the time complexity of this loop is O(n^2).
And here is how to calculate the value of sum:
sum = n + 2*n + 3*n + ... + n*n
    = n * (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)
    = n*n*(n + 1)/2

So the second loop will execute n*n*(n + 1)/2 times. The time complexity is O(n^3). In the context of algorithm analysis, we focus on the dominant term as the input size grows large, the previous O(n^2) will be ignored.
Then the final complexity of your code is O(n^3).
